# Using `nohup` to Import MySQL Dump on Debian Server

Tags: debian, mysql, nohup

I am trying to import a mysqldump file into my mysql database, but my (putty) connection to the server keeps timing out halfway through.

I tried to use `nohup . . . . &` but this doesn't appear to work.

My Command is

```
nohup sudo mysql -hlocalhost -P3306 -uxxxxxx -pxxxxxx < /var/lib/mysql/backups/dump.sql &
```

Which I believe should run it in the background, and persist after my connection to the server dies.
However, when I then type `jobs` to see if it is running, it says:

```
    [1]   Stopped                 nohup sudo mysql -hlocalhost -P3306 -uxxxxx -pxxxxx < /var/lib/mysql/backups/dump.sql
```

Am I doing something wrong, or have I completely misunderstood the purpose of `nohup . . . . &`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sudo` probably asks for a password and nohup disconnects the process from the controlling terminal. Use that instead:

```
sudo sh -c 'nohup mysql -hlocalhost -P3306 -uxxxxxx -pxxxxxx < /var/lib/mysql/backups/dump.sql &'
```

Comment: that's great cheers, it worked perfectly.

Comment: This solution won't work if db password has special xters. The solution is to use quotes around the password, as per http://superuser.com/questions/123928/escaping-a-password-using-mysqldump-console

Comment: **IMPORTANT!!** This works perfectly, but note if an error occurs this will exit. add `-f` to force the insert. Having to start all over again isn't fun so I thought I'd share!

Comment: Per Mugoma's comment above, the corrected command would be something like `sudo sh -c "nohup mysql -hlocalhost -P3306 -uxxxxxx -p'x$$$xx' < /var/lib/mysql/backups/dump.sql &"`.   Note change of single and double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

First, *switch* to root with

```
sudo -i
```

Then,

```
nohup sh -c 'mysql -hlocalhost -P3306 -uxxxxxx -pxxxxxx < /var/lib/mysql/backups/dump.sql' &
```

Answer (score 2):

I 'may' have solved this by leaving out the `&`, and then running `nohup . . .`, then pressing `ctrl-z`, then exiting from putty.

So far the MySQL connection appears to be still running